# When a wrap a video around a sphere, how do I get rid of the mesh effect?

Tags: rendering, mesh, uv, video

[image: Video wrapped on a sphere]

As can be seen, there are squares visible on the rendered output. I want to get rid of that and want the video to be smooth. How can I do that? Or what settings am I missing out on?

Comment: set the mesh shading to smooth (toolbox > tools > shading) doesn't work?

Comment: @m.ardito It worked. I had forgotten about this option. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: use smooth shading and a subsurf modifier